# Why does C++ not allow multiple types in one auto statement?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, auto

The 2011 C++ standard introduced the new keyword `auto`, which can be used for defining variables instead of a type, i.e.

```
auto p=make_pair(1,2.5);                   // pair<int,double>
auto i=std::begin(c), end=std::end(c);     // decltype(std::begin(c))
```

In the second line, `i` and `end` are of the same type, referred to as `auto`. The standard does not allow

```
auto i=std::begin(container), e=std::end(container), x=*i;
```

when `x` would be of different type. **My question**: why does the standard not allow this last line? It could be allowed by interpreting `auto` not as representing some to-be-decuded type, but as indicating that the type of *any* variable declared `auto` shall be deduced from its assigned value. Is there any good reason for the C++11 standard to not follow this approach?

There is actually a use case for this, namely in the initialisation statement of `for` loops:

```
for(auto i=std::begin(c), end=std::end(c), x=*i;  i!=end;  ++i, x+=*i)
{ ... }
```

when the scope of the variables `i`, `end`, and `x` is limited to the `for` loop. AFAIK, this cannot be achieved in C++ unless those variables have a common type. **Is this correct?** (ugly tricks of putting all types inside a `struct` excluded)

There may also be use cases in some variadic template applications.

Comment: Almost all questions that are of the form "Why does the Standard say blah blah" have one of these answers:  1) Backward compatibility to C, 2) They didn't have time to do something else, 3) [insert unsubstantiated opinion here]

Comment: @JohnDibling I disagree. There are often very good reasons (beyond backward compatibility, which doesn't seem to apply here). I was wondering whether there is a good reason here.

Comment: John's right. Almost all such questions end up with answers of that form. He's not saying that the good reason does not exist. It's just that it's often not well known or documented. I don't know, can you get minutes of the standard committee meetings? Looks like you can: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/  I suggest you scour these.

Comment: OK, this looks relevant: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1737.pdf

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Good catch. However, this proposal would not allow different types within one `auto` statement. It would merely allow to use the first type deduction for all following types, i.e. `auto x=3,y;` when `y` is automatically `int`. The argument seems to be *consistency*: any variable declaration of the form `type x[=initialier], y[=initialier], ...` shall always only define variables of the same type, even for `type`=`auto`.

Comment: I didn't say that proposal would do what you wanted. Just that it discussed the issue. You know where to find the information now. You can surely answer the question yourself at this point.

Comment: `auto triple = make_tuple(begin(c),end(c),*begin(c))`.  I like this solution, even though you said "ugly tricks of putting all types inside a struct excluded)"  **:-)**

Comment: Actually, "`auto`" is not a new keyword. It has a different meaning in C and pre-2011 C++. (It indicated that its declared objects had scoped lifetime, neither `extern`, `static`, nor `thread_local`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of consistency with non-`auto` declarations.

This:

```
auto n = 42, *p = &n;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int n = 42, *p = &n;
```

where the types `int` and `int*` are derived from the initializers.  In both cases, even though `int` and `int*` are different types, they're permitted to be in the same declaration because of their close syntactic relation. (By the "declaration follows use" rule that C and C++ declarations *almost* follow, you're defining both `n` and `*p` as being of type `int`.)

It would have been possible to permit unrelated types in the same declaration:

```
auto n = 42, x = 1.5;
```

but the above would have to be equivalent to two separate declarations:

```
int n = 42; double x = 1.5;
```

I think the idea when adding `auto` was to make a minimal change to the language, permitting the type to be inferred from an initializer but not changing the kinds of declarations that are possible.

Even without `auto`, you could define an `int` and an `int*` in a `for` loop header:

```
for (int n = 42, *p = &n; expr1; expr2) { /* ... / }
```

but you couldn't declare an `int` and a `double` together.  The addition of `auto` simply didn't change that.

Outside the context of a `for` loop, it's generally much better to use separate declarations anyway. Shoving a lot of different declarations into a `for` loop is arguably a bad idea in most cases. And for the (probably rare) cases where you want a lot of declarations, you can just put them above the loop, something like this:

```
auto i=std::begin(c), end=std::end(c),
for( x=*i;  i!=end;  ++i, x+=*i) {
    // ...
}
```

adding another set of `{` `}` around the whole thing if you want to limit the scope. (In this case, you'd probably want `end` to be `const` anyway.)

Comment: okay. But this argument is not really a strong objection against multi-type `auto`. But it seems indeed the argument used.

Comment: If `auto` worked the way you stipulate, then `auto x = 1.5, y = 0;` would have different meaning from `double x = 1.5, y = 0;`

Answer (score 5):

According to the final revision of the accepted proposal for this feature, [N1737](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1737.pdf),a possible multi-declarator `auto` implementation is as follows: (from Section 6)

> We believe it is possible to achieve both consistent form and
>   consistent behavior. We do so by inserting (for purposes of
>   exposition) an intermediate __Deduced_type definition, and applying
>   this type consistently in the as-if expansion:

```
  // Listing 12
 typedef int __Deduced_type; // exposition only
  __Deduced_type a = 1;
 // decltype(a) is int
 __Deduced_type b = 3.14; // decltype(b) is int
  __Deduced_type * c = new float; // error; decltype(c) would be int *
```

> Not only do we achieve consistency of both form and behavior via such a
>   reconciled formulation, we also address more complicated situations.
>   For example, when the leading declarator includes a ptr-operator:

```
 // Listing 13 
auto * a = new int(1), b = 3.14, * c = new float;
```

> our formulation attaches semantics as-if declared:

```
// Listing 14 
 typedef int __Deduced_type; // exposition only
 __Deduced_type * a = new int(1); // decltype(a) is int *
 __Deduced_type b = 3.14; // decltype(b) is int
 __Deduced_type * c = new float; // error; decltype(c) would be int *
```

As shown by this possible implementation, changing the type would be invalid, and as such would cause an error.
This feature was implemented this way because otherwise it would be different than other types of multi-variable declarations.
I remember seeing a discussion about whether or not to allow changing types, but I cannot remember where.  IIRC, they decided that it would be harder to implement, but another reason could be that it was dropped because they could not come to a consensus on when to choose different types (the new behavior) or when to implicitly convert to the deduced type of the first declared variable (the old behavior).

Comment: This is just copied from the document linked by David's comment. And it does not allow multi-type `auto`. The reason seems merely consistency with other statements, which obviously cannot have multi-type semantics if a type must be specified.

Comment: At the time I posted this I did not see David's comment; I found the PDF myself.

Answer (score 2):

C++17 finally brought structured binding declarations, which solve your problem:

```
auto [ i, s, f ] = std::tuple(42, "Hello World", 5.0);
```

This declares i as the integer 42, s as a `const char*` to a zero-terminated string "Hello World" and f as the double precision number 5.0.

I am not aware of a solution without the intermediate `std::tuple`. If you use a fully conformant C++20 compiler, you can also use an alias template to abbrevate that `std::tuple` as in this example:

```
template<typename ... ARGS> using T = std::tuple<ARGS ...>;
auto [ i, s, f ] = T(42, "Hello World", 5.0);
```

This compiles fine with `g++-10` in both C++17 and C++20 mode, though it should actually compile only in C++20 mode. C++17 does not allow template parameter deduction for alias templates, not even in the most simple case, where the template parameter list is forwarded 1:1 to the aliased template.